# Insert two Entities and join the primary key

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to insert data into two tables simultaneously while having the primary key from table 1 inserted into table 2.

Entity 1:

```
@Entity (tableName = "all_equip")
public class EquipInfo implements Comparable <EquipInfo>{

@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
private int equipId;
private int gymId;
private int userId;
private boolean isActive;
private String equipGrade;
...other
```

Entity 2:

```
@Entity (tableName = "my_equip_data")
public class MyEquipData {
@PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
private int userId;
private int equipId;
...other
```

What I need is that when a new entity 1 is inserted into all_equip, a new Entity 2 (which contains the users specific data) is also inserted into my_equip_data but with the primary key (equipId) from Entity 1.

I am using SQLite with Room and the simple `@Insert` queries.

My Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface EquipInfoDao {
@Insert
void insert (EquipInfo equipInfo);
```

My Utils:

```
public Boolean addNewEquip (Context context, EquipInfo equipInfo) {
    Database.getInstance(context).equipInfoDao().insert(equipInfo);
    return true;
}
```

I have managed to join these tables in other queries but am unsure on how to insert the first Entity, retrieve the equipId for that newly inserted entry and then add it as a foreign key in the second Entity. All in one OnClickListener.

Comment: You say you're using sqlite, but have added a <mysql> tag. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room allows you to return the primary key from the insert query by specifying the return type as `long`. So you can run the two inserts in a transaction, with the second using the returned key. Something like this:

```
@Insert
long insert1(Entity1 e)

@Insert
void insert2(Entity2 e)

@Transaction
insertBoth(Entity1 e1, Entity2 e2) {

    long primaryKey1 = insert(e1);
    e2.setKey1(primaryKey1);
    insert(e2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add Constructors to the Entity's that allow them to be built/populated when instantiated you can use something like :-

```
dao.insertMyEquipData((new MyEquipData(5000,dao.insertEquipInfo(new EquipInfo(1000,5000,true,"Grade 1")))));
dao.insertMyEquipData((new MyEquipData(6000,dao.insertEquipInfo(new EquipInfo(2000,6000,false,"Grade 2")))));
```

- this adds 2 EquipInfo's and also 2 MyEquipData's with the equipId being passed into the MyEquipData

The @Dao being unchanged as such it being :-

```
@Dao
interface EquipInfoDao {

    @Insert
    long insertEquipInfo(EquipInfo equipInfo);

    @Insert
    long insertMyEquipData(MyEquipData equipData);
}
```

However the Entity's have been changed

- long's instead of int's for id's

  - *it's more correct to use longs and it makes no difference in the database as values will be saved with as little storage as possible*
- default and @Ignore'd constructors have been added to facilitate the above usage.

**EquipInfo** :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "all_equip")
public class EquipInfo /*implements Comparable <EquipInfo>*/ {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long equipId;
    private long gymId;
    private long userId;
    private boolean isActive;
    private String equipGrade;

    public EquipInfo(){}

    @Ignore
    public EquipInfo(long gymId, long userId, boolean isActive, String equipGrade) {
        this.gymId = gymId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.equipGrade = equipGrade;
    }

    public void setEquipId(long equipId) {
        this.equipId = equipId;
    }

    public long getEquipId() {
        return equipId;
    }

    public void setGymId(long gymId) {
        this.gymId = gymId;
    }

    public long getGymId() {
        return gymId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setEquipGrade(String equipGrade) {
        this.equipGrade = equipGrade;
    }

    public String getEquipGrade() {
        return equipGrade;
    }
}
```

**MyEquipData** :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_equip_data")
public class MyEquipData {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private long userId;
    private long equipId;

    public MyEquipData(){}

    @Ignore
    public MyEquipData(long userId, long equipId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.equipId = equipId;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setEquipId(long equipId) {
        this.equipId = equipId;
    }

    public long getEquipId() {
        return equipId;
    }
}
```

**Result** (Database Inspector)

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike. this helped me understand a little bit better. Very much appreciated!